# SQL DELETE query with NOT IN clause not working

Tags: sql-server

i have a simple delete query i have two tables table1 and table2

the query is

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE  end_time NOT IN (SELECT end_time
                        FROM   table2
                        WHERE  comp_name = 'component')
       AND id = 'id'
```

the query does not delete the record what am i missing here i tried to change the first condition with second but it deletes without checking the condition 2

what are the alternatives here?

i am wondering what is the actual problem here the query runs without errors but it is not correct.

Comment: Try to run each of the condition in a select query to see if getting any results

Comment: there is no result in the select query when i use the both conditions but there is common results on each conditions

Comment: Try `exists` instead of `in`. `In` can act 'strange' when you got null values in it.

Comment: The select recommendation is a great way to determine what rows will be deleted without actually deleting them.  Use it to tune your query without having to re-insert data each time.  Since you are checking if end_time from table1 is in table2, remember the "IN" operator expects a precise match.  Even if sub-seconds are different, there will not be a match.

Comment: @user3786134 - Good question. Here are some related posts - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479005/not-exists-vs-not-in and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be `alias` should fix your problem since the both the tables have same column name `end_time`. `Outer query` column can be referred inside the `subquery` that might be the problem.

```
DELETE FROM table1 
WHERE  end_time NOT IN (SELECT b.end_time
                        FROM   table2 B
                        WHERE  b.comp_name = 'component')
       AND id = 'id'
```

**Update :** Try this delete because you may have `null` values in your sub query where `NOT IN` will fail. Check this post [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129077/not-in-clause-and-null-values)

```
DELETE a
FROM   table1 a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   table2 B
                   WHERE  b.comp_name = 'component'
                          AND a.end_time = b.end_time)
       AND id = 'id'
```